# Android play youtube videos in countries that blocks youtube.com

Tags: android, video, youtube, proxy, android-webview

I have an android app that plays youtube videos in it.I am using youtube android player sdk. Youtube has been blocked in some countries and I wanna play videos also these countries and I dont want to asked user to install another apps like hotspotshield vpn. How can I do that any idea?